# Emulate "Refresh All" in xlsx from R (on Linux nonetheless)

Tags: r, excel

I am using the `xlsx` package in R in order to perform some operation on an Excel file that also contains a connection to three MySQL tables. These tables are updated regularly, and I'd like to update the - the equivalent of "Refresh all" button in the Excel menu. Updating the files when on file open is not an option.

I did have a look at all the workbook related function in `xlsx` package, but can't find anything that does the job:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
.jmethods(wb)
```

All of this happens on Linux, but a Windows solution will do just fine.

Any ideas ?